# How to create a wave sound, in R, given a specified deciBel level?

Tags: r, audio, waveform, decibel

I R, thanks to the library `sound`, we are able to create a sine wave:

```
s1 <- Sine(650, 1, 44100, 16, 2)
```

Plotting the waveform we obtain an image like this:

```
plot(s1[1:100])
```

[image: waveform]

The waveform moves in the interval [-1, +1]. If I play it, to what deciBel does it correspond?

How to generate a wave sound (with the same parameters), with a specified deciBel level (i.e. a wave sound, frequency 650Hz, duration 1 sec, sampling rate 44100, 16 bits, 2 channels, 55dB)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't this depend upon the player?  I'm not an audio expert but if the volume control in Media Player (or whatever) or your PC is changed, so will the decibels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess you want to change the amplitude right? There is no straightforward way to change amplitude in `sound` the way you want, because it's very basic package. Try [`tuneR`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuneR/) or [`seewave`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/) packages for much more advanced options and control (for example [afilter](http://rug.mnhn.fr/seewave/HTML/MAN/afilter.html) in `seewave` could be a good solution, but unfortunately I couldn't run it in R 2.14 - not compatible).

What you could do in a simple way is to use `normalize` to change the volume, but it doesn't work for the 'default' amplitude in `sound` package. For example, if you produce this sine wave

```
 s1 <- .6*Sine(650, 1, 44100, 16, 2)
```

you can normalize it by

```
 s2 <- normalize(s1)
```

And you can hear (and see on the plot) that the s2 is louder.

Comment: So is the range [-1, +1], the amplitude of my tone? Do I need to convert the 55 dB to magnitude, in order to find a constant, like the 0.6 in your example? And do I need to consider, also, the characteristics of my headphone, to be sure that the produced sound will be exactly 55dB?

Comment: Tommaso -- you need to learn a lot about sound and audio equipment.  This is not an R question or even a software question.  For one thing, "dB" is not an absolute value: it's a relative value.  Google "dBa," for example.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You're right, deciBel is, by definition, a relative value. I googled something, but I didn't find any answer: what parameters do I need to consider, in order to create a sound that, on my headphones, will be perceived like a 55dB tone? Thanks for your help.